# EF Core: how to make a request better

Tags: sql, performance, azure-sql-database, query-optimization, linq-to-entities

I have a table `Device` with 1M records. Table has approx 40 columns, for most requests need only 10 of them.

The table has relationships with:

- `Carrier` table with 1000 rows and 50+ columns.
- `DeviceModel` table with only 10 records and 5 columns, but `DeviceModel` table is linked with table `DeviceCharacteristic` (only 5 records and 3 columns) via `DeviceModel_DeviceCharacteristic_Mapping` (many-to-many relationship), this table has 2 columns and 20 rows. All these 3 tables with 'static' data, which can be changed very rare.
- `DeviceDataUsage` table with 2M records

My default LinqToEntities request is:

```
var query = _context.Devices
                    .Include(a => a.Carrier)
                    .Include(a => a.DeviceModel)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.CharacteristicMappings)
                    .AsQueryable<Device>();

query = query.Where(d => d.CarrierId != null);
query = query.Where(p => p.SyncVerizon || p.SyncSureMdm);
query = query.Where(d => d.DeviceModel.CharacteristicMappings.Any(t => t.CharacteristicId == deviceCharacteristicId));

IOrderedQueryable<Device> orderedQuery= query.OrderByDescending(device => device.LastConnectionDate);

var devices = new PagedList<DeviceDisplayAdminDto>(orderedQuery.ProjectTo<DeviceDisplayAdminDto>(_mapperConfig), pageIndex, pageSize);
```

where `DeviceDisplayAdminDto` is:

```
public class DeviceDisplayAdminDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public int? DeviceModelId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModelDescription { get; set; }
    public string StatusString { get; set; }
    public DeviceStatus Status { get; set; }

    public bool SyncVerizon { get; set; }
    public bool SyncSureMdm { get; set; }

    public long? DataUsageCurrentMonth { get; set; }
    public long? DataUsageCurrentDay { get; set; }
    public int? CarrierId { get; set; }
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }

    public List<string> Characteristics { get; set; }
    public bool IsDataUsageExist { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastConnectionDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsInactiveLongTimeAndNotSuspended { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspensionRequestAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper rules:

```
 CreateMap<Device, DeviceDisplayAdminDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Status, o => o.MapFrom(s  => s.Status))
            .ForMember(d => d.StatusString, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Status.ToString().SplitByWords()))
            .ForMember(d => d.DeviceModelDescription, o => o.MapFrom(s => (s.DeviceModel != null) ? s.DeviceModel.GetDeviceModelDescription() : Tms.Core.Constants.Common.NotSet))
            .ForMember(d => d.CarrierName, o => o.MapFrom(s => (s.Carrier != null) ? s.Carrier.Name : string.Empty))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsSuspensionRequestAllowed, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DeviceModel.CharacteristicMappings.Where(a => a.Characteristic.IsSuspensionRequestAllowed).Count() > 0))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsInactiveLongTimeAndNotSuspended, o => o.MapFrom(s => 
                (s.Status == DeviceStatus.Active || s.Status == DeviceStatus.PreActive)
                && s.DeviceModel.CharacteristicMappings.Where(a => a.Characteristic.IsSuspensionRequestAllowed).Count() > 0
                && (s.LastConnectionDate == null 
                || s.LastConnectionDate.Value < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-Tms.Core.Constants.DeviceManagementConstants.SuspensionDays))))
            .ForMember(d => d.IsDataUsageExist, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.VerizonDataUsage.Count() > 0))
            .ForMember(d => d.Characteristics, o => o.MapFrom(s => (s.DeviceModel != null) ? s.DeviceModel.CharacteristicMappings.Select(a => a.Characteristic.Characteristic) : null))
            ;
```

This request for 25 top items from 1M records executes for 4-6 seconds. I want to improve performance.

So, as I understand, mapping with related tables is doing only for selected (in my case 25 items) records, right? And I can be relaxed with performance of linking ?

Any sense to create a view and select from it? Which indexes are necessary by default? What else can help me?

**ADDED**

Generated SQL (truly to say, I don't understand how it's so complex)

```
SELECT [t].[CarrierId], 
    CASE WHEN [c].[Id] IS NOT NULL THEN [c].[Name] ELSE N'' END, 
    CASE WHEN [d0].[Id] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, 
    [t].[Id], 
    [c].[Id], 
    [d0].[Id], 
    [t0].[Characteristic], 
    [t0].[DeviceModelId], 
    [t0].[CharacteristicId], 
    [t0].[Id], 
    [t].[DataUsageCurrentDay], 
    [t].[DataUsageCurrentMonth], 
    [d0].[ApplyType], 
    [d0].[Deleted], 
    [d0].[Manufacturer], 
    [d0].[Model], 
    [d3].[DeviceModelId], 
    [d3].[CharacteristicId], 
    [t].[DeviceModelId], 
    [t].[IMEI], 
    CASE WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DeviceVerizonDataUsage] AS [d4] WHERE [t].[Id] = [d4].[DeviceId]) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, 
    CASE WHEN ([t].[Status] IN (1, 0) AND (( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DeviceModel_DeviceCharacteristic_Mapping] AS [d5] INNER JOIN [DeviceCharacteristic] AS [d6] ON [d5].[CharacteristicId] = [d6].[Id] WHERE (([d0].[Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([d0].[Id] = [d5].[DeviceModelId])) AND ([d6].[IsSuspensionRequestAllowed] = CAST(1 AS bit))) > 0)) AND (([t].[LastConnectionDate] IS NULL) OR ([t].[LastConnectionDate] < DATEADD(day, CAST(-90.0E0 AS int), GETUTCDATE()))) THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, 
    CASE WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DeviceModel_DeviceCharacteristic_Mapping] AS [d7] INNER JOIN [DeviceCharacteristic] AS [d8] ON [d7].[CharacteristicId] = [d8].[Id] WHERE (([d0].[Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([d0].[Id] = [d7].[DeviceModelId])) AND ([d8].[IsSuspensionRequestAllowed] = CAST(1 AS bit))) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, 
    [t].[LastConnectionDate], 
    [t].[Name], 
    [t].[Status], 
    [t].[SyncSureMdm], 
    [t].[SyncVerizon] 
    FROM ( SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CarrierId], [d].[DataUsageCurrentDay], [d].[DataUsageCurrentMonth], [d].[DeviceModelId], [d].[IMEI], [d].[LastConnectionDate], [d].[Name], [d].[Status], [d].[SyncSureMdm], [d].[SyncVerizon] FROM [Device] AS [d] WHERE ([d].[CarrierId] IS NOT NULL) AND (([d].[SyncVerizon] = CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ([d].[SyncSureMdm] = CAST(1 AS bit))) ORDER BY [d].[Name] OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY ) AS [t] LEFT JOIN [Carrier] AS [c] ON [t].[CarrierId] = [c].[Id] LEFT JOIN [DeviceModel] AS [d0] ON [t].[DeviceModelId] = [d0].[Id] LEFT JOIN ( SELECT [d2].[Characteristic], [d1].[DeviceModelId], [d1].[CharacteristicId], [d2].[Id] FROM [DeviceModel_DeviceCharacteristic_Mapping] AS [d1] INNER JOIN [DeviceCharacteristic] AS [d2] ON [d1].[CharacteristicId] = [d2].[Id] ) AS [t0] ON [d0].[Id] = [t0].[DeviceModelId] LEFT JOIN [DeviceModel_DeviceCharacteristic_Mapping] AS [d3] ON [d0].[Id] = [d3].[DeviceModelId] ORDER BY [t].[Name], [t].[Id], [c].[Id], [d0].[Id], [t0].[DeviceModelId], [t0].[CharacteristicId], [t0].[Id], [d3].[DeviceModelId]
```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't know why, but even longer...

Comment: There is no order by date here. So a part of your query is in memory. You should avoid that. What's the time for each part, in memory and in sql?

Comment: Also, what's the time for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DeviceVerizonDataUsage]...`?